# How to make nested query work in group by context?

Tags: sql

I have a simple example table like the one below.

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ id2 ┆ v   ┆ v2  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 9   │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 8   │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 5   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 6   ┆ 4   │
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 7   ┆ 3   │
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 8   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 9   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I want to achieve effectively the following:

```
SELECT id, id2, sum((v - mean(v)) * v2) / sum(abs(v - mean(v))) as res
FROM df
GROUP BY id, id2
```

However, the query above does not work with error message like 'nested aggregations are not supported'.

My question is: is it possible to make the above query works without resorting to `OVER` clause?

The result I expect is:

```
id id2 res
 1   1  -1
 2   1  -1
 3   2  -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for

```
WITH mean_values AS (
  SELECT id, id2, AVG(v) AS mean_v
  FROM df
  GROUP BY id, id2
)
SELECT df.id, df.id2, SUM((df.v - mean_v) * df.v2) / SUM(ABS(df.v - mean_v)) AS res
FROM df
JOIN mean_values ON df.id = mean_values.id AND df.id2 = mean_values.id2
GROUP BY df.id, df.id2;
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to give me the expected results. But just curious about whether it is possible to do this just under one GROUP BY clause? Otherwise, as in your code, there are two GROUP BY and one JOIN, so the performance will take a hit when the table is very large.

Comment: In the case of your specific query, it is not possible to achieve the desired result using only one GROUP BY clause. The reason is that you need to calculate the mean of v within each group (id and id2) and then use that mean value in the subsequent calculations.

When you perform calculations that involve both aggregations (such as mean) and non-aggregated columns (such as v and v2), it typically requires a two-step process. The first step is to calculate the aggregations (mean) within each group, and the second step is to use those aggregated values to perform further calculations.

Comment: Therefore, in your case, you need the separate GROUP BY clause in the CTE (mean_values) to calculate the mean values per group. Then, in the main query, you need another GROUP BY clause to group the results by id and id2 and perform the final calculations using the mean values.

Comment: Curious why simple aggregation like sum(abs(v - avg(v))) is treated as nested aggregation and not allowed in SQL. I observe that when I have a lot of rows and columns in the table, performance will be hit quite a lot by redundent GROUP BY and JOIN.

Comment: @lebesgue It's treated as nested because-- to evaluate your expression, `avg(v)` needs to be computed before it can be fed to the outer `sum()`. This is different from calculating `avg()` and `sum()` independently, in which case you wouldn't get an error.

Comment: -- $5.99 please.